# Every time I try to download an app it it says unable to install cannot preform following tasks

Tags: software-installation

I haven't tried to fix it much beaus i dont really know how beaus i'm a beginner

i'm on 22.04.3 LTS. if thats helps
if anyone knows what to do please help me

I hope I put the right tag if not please correct me

the exact error message is.

Unable to install (app name):
cannot preform following tasks:

Im just trying to download it off the ubuntu software app

Comment: There could be many reasons. We will need the exact error message.

Comment: We also need the location of the package you downloaded. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].